# Pygame Mixer unable to be used

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I was trying to use pygame.mixer to generate sine wave audio, however, running the following code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
```

gives me the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: use mixer: dlopen(/Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libsndfile.1.0.34.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
(ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libsndfile.1.0.34.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown))
  pygame.mixer.get_sdl_mixer_version()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.get_sdl_mixer_version()
  File "/Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(missing_msg)
NotImplementedError: mixer module not available (ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libsndfile.1.0.34.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Users/kids/PycharmProjects/PySynth/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libmp3lame.0.dylib: cannot load 'libmp3lame.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown))
```

In my venv, I checked to see if libmp3lame.0.dylib existed, which it did. I suspected that it could be a problem with my pygame installation, so I reinstalled the libary. No luck. For reference, I am using:

- MacOS 10.14 (Mojave)
- Python 3.9.6
- Pygame 2.4.0
- Venv
- Pycharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pygame buildconfig.

Fortunately it is fixed in pygame-ce (pygame community edition), the modern community fork of pygame.

Pygame-ce is totally backwards compatible with pygame, and has some additional features (and this bug is fixed). You can even still import as pygame.

Try `pip uninstall pygame` and then `pip install pygame-ce --pre` (The pre flag is necessary because the bug fix is only in a dev release right now)